# Draw curve with varying line width

Tags: ios, core-graphics, bezier

I know how to draw curve with Core Graphic or using UIBezierPath.

But, I want to draw a curve that is wide to begin with and thin at the end:

[image]

I searched many question about curve, bezier path or something similar on Google. But i can't find any ideal for implementing it.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can create closed path for the curve boundary and fill it with color.

Comment: Do you have some way except this way ? I dont want draw closed path for the curve boundary and fill color. I want it can be useable. Some thing like [FeSpecialCurve startAngle:endAngle:percentThin:] ... or ...

Comment: There is no such method. If you know Core Graphics creating your curve is just a matter of school math. If it's a hard for you you can create image of the curve in an image editor instead of drawing it.

Comment: okay, thank for quick reply :]. I have just had ideal for that. I should try and update my answer soon.

Comment: Do you only want to draw it or is it supposed to animate (for example grow) as well?

Comment: There are a couple ways I can think of to do this... both are very complex.

Comment: In CSS, it's very easy to implement it. But, iOS is very complex. It supposed to animate.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods that immediately come to mind are...

**Calculating the path**

This is probably the most complex. It would involve calculating the path for the entire shape and adding this as a path and filling it.

**Using a line method**

You create a series of points that will lie along the centre line of your curve. Maybe 5 points between each point.

Then at each point you can use that as a centre point of a line perpendicular to the tangent of the curve at the point.

The perpendicular line will have a length which you can calculate depending on how far through the curve you are.

Then use this line to create a square path to the line from the previous point.

Then fill that square.

Move to the next point. Add the line and create a box back to the previous line and so on.

At the end are a circle with centre point of the last point. This will create the end.

It's complex but doable if you split down the functions.